# What's the better way to load external resources with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, load

I need load external resources from another server like css, template, data... but I don't know what is the better way for do it.
Naturally when we load external file there is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem.

So, the solutions are:

**- jsonp**

**- allow transfer with proxy.php, like here:**

```
// If I want style.css the url for ajax call is /proxy.php?file=style.css
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
```

How we behave in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can be transfered cross-domain using a `<link>` tag which you can generate in javascript and append to `<head>`, scripts can be appended to the `<head>` just like css or loaded using jquery's `$.getScript`, and data can be transferred using `jsonp` with jquery's `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`.

Any other forms of data will require a server-side proxy.

I personally prefer to use `jsonp` when transferring data, however when that is not possible, the only other choice is a server-side proxy.

Comment: But if I load the scripts and the styles using tags I can't control the loading, what I would is control the transfer with deferred, in this way I will know when the css is available.

Comment: There are two ways to use css on a page; One is <link> the other is <style>. If you request the contents of a css file on your same-domain server from a cross-domain server, you can then return that css as plain text, then on complete, append it within style tags and append the style tags to the dom. To me it seems like a whole lot of trouble just to load some different css styles from a different domain.

Comment: yes but I need load these resources in a second moment. However, my issue is what's the right way for transfer these resources, an unique jsonp that contains all or an server-side proxy. 
I don't look for a solution, I seek the right way. Thanks!

Comment: The datatype you transfer it as doesn't matter as long as you can pull the data from the return and stick it within style tags and append to head.

Comment: What I want to do is have a button that when I click it must appear a popup. The css, the data and the html of this popup are on another server. So, if I want do it there is a unique issue, how transfer data? is not it? Tell me if I'm wrong analysis.

Comment: could you use an iframe inside the dialog? or do you have to grab the contents and use them directly.

Comment: I only need show this popup and I'm looking for the correct technology. Iframe is better than ajax request?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to show in the popup and what the purpose of the popup is.

Comment: I need to darken the body, show a div in position absolute on the center of the body e close all with a X on the top right. But I think that iframe isn't for me. I will use a jsonp (that wrap all resources) and one ajax request.